# For any measurable set B, does there exist a closed set containing B such that their difference is small?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have seen this lemma several times:

*Fix $\epsilon >0$. For any measurable set $B$, there exists an **open** set $U$ containing $B$ such that $\mu (U \backslash B) <\epsilon$.*

Can the statement be changed to ask:

For any measurable set $B$, does there exist a **closed** set $V$ containing $B$ such that $\mu (V \backslash B) <\epsilon$?

**Remark** The proof for the original lemma involves only the definition of outer measure for $B$. That proof will fail here because, I think, a union of open sets is necessarily still open so we can take that as our U. However a union of closed sets is not necessarily closed so we can't take that as our V. Can someone exhibit a quick counterexample?

Comment: What closed subsets of $\mathbb R$ contain the set $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers?

Comment: Nice.

**Solution**: Any closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ must be $\mathbb{R}$ itself, so this provides a counterexample.

Comment: Now do you see how to get a counterexample for your question where $B$ is an **open** set?

Comment: Oh? Is that a condition that you're adding?

I suppose one could have the following lemma:

*Fix $\epsilon >0$. For any open set $B$, there exists an **open** set $U$ containing $B$ such that $\mu (U \backslash B) <\epsilon$.*

This is true because all open sets are measurable.

Comment: In my first example I gave an example of an $F_\sigma$ set $B$ (namely the rational numbers) for which there is no closed set $V\supseteq B$ such that $V\setminus B$ is small. In my second comment I asked you to give an example of an **open** set $B$ for which there is no closed set $V\supseteq B$ such that $V\setminus B$ is small. In this, my third comment, I say: never mind.

Comment: I see.
Well I've scouted around and I found a counterexample to that as well: remove a fat Cantor set from $[0,1]$ to obtain a dense open subset of $[0,1]$ whose measure is $<1$. That gives an open set whose closure differs from it in measure.

Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: That's more or less what I had in mind, a dense open set of small measure. For instance, using the lemma quoted at the beginning of your question, there is an open set $U$ containing $\mathbb Q$ such that $\mu(\mathbb U)=\mu(U\setminus\mathbb Q)\lt\epsilon.$